# How to find how many characters are in each element of a string array

Tags: java

if I have an string array tmp={"happy","sad"} i know tmp.length will give me 2, but how do I access each element, and count the number of characters i.e tmp[0] would have 5 charcaters and tmp[1] would have 3 characters

Comment: call `tmp[0].length()`

Answer (score 1):

`tmp[0].length()`

If `tmp` is an array of strings, then you can call any `String` method on any individual element by using the square bracket notation as such.

The same is true for any array of any type of object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string's [length method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29).

```
tmp[0].length() -> 5
tmp[1].length() -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To access each element, you can use a 'for loop' to iterate through the array and access each item as you go.  For example:

```
for(int i=0;i<tmp.length;i++){
  System.out.println(Integer.toString(tmp.[i].length()));
  // or do whatever you want with tmp[i].length()    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String s : tmp){
    s.length()
}
```